# Why I can not change file permissions?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, chmod

I entered **sudo su** and I am root now.
Is it because my files are on NTFS partition?
Despite any numbers I enter the file permission is 777

```
chmod 644 index.php
```

Comment: NTFS does not comfortably support Linux file permissions. See [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](//askubuntu.com/q/11840)/

Comment: In Linux, the Microsoft file systems NTFS and FAT32 get their file permissions, when the partitions are mounted. After that the permissions cannot be modified (unless you unmount and mount again with modified mount options). You can control/modify it (typically read-only or read/write) according to the link in the previous comments.